# AppleScript Clicking On dialog box

Tags: macos, applescript

In PCSX, (ps1 emulator), i'm trying to automate the steps to play an iso. So, i'm doing this:

```
set thepath to path to me
set thesecondpath to POSIX path of thepath
set thethirdpath to "Contents/PSX/ROMS/img.bin"
set thefourthpath to "/Contents/PSX/PCSX.app"
set thefifthpath to thesecondpath & thefourthpath
set theultimatepath to thesecondpath & thethirdpath

tell application thefifthpath
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "i" using {command down}
        keystroke theultimatepath
        delay 1.0
        tell process "PCSX"
            click button "Go"
        end tell
        key code 53
    end tell
end tell
```

Running from the AppleScript Editor won't work. I made it to work running from the App it creates. PCSX and the img.bin are inside the Generated Package.

after pressing `command+i`, it opens a `"Go to the folder"` dialog, and i need to click `Go` and then `Open`

But doing this way, it won't find the dialog box. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If Go and Open are the default buttons, try:

```
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke return
    delay 2
    keystroke return
end tell
```

Although I don't have PCX installed here is an example of how to click the Go button from Finder's Go to Folder command.

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Finder"
        click button "Go" of window "Go to Folder"
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: This is what i have done to make it work, but, for learning purposes, i wanted to know how to simmulate the Click function... Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason your script won’t work from AppleScript Editor is that the “me” in “path to me” is the application that ran the AppleScript. When you are running the AppleScript in AppleScript Editor, that means AppleScript Editor itself. When you saved your AppleScript as a script application and ran it, the path to me pointed to your script application, because it was running its own AppleScript.

Also, this is incorrect:

```
tell process "Finder"
        click button "Go" of window "Go to Folder"
end tell
```

The “Go” button is not on the window “Go to Folder.” It’s on a sheet which is attached to a Finder window which has the name of whatever folder is currently being viewed. So you have to describe the button as being on sheet 1 of window 1:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Finder"
        click button "Go" of sheet 1 of window 1
    end tell
end tell
```

… but keep in mind that in another app, a similar looking button on a sheet may be on sheet 1 of group 1 of group 2 of window 3. UI Scripting is complicated.